# How to count ratio hourly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I`m stuck a bit with understanding of my further actions while performing queries.

I have two tables **"A"(date, response, b_id)** and **"B"(id, country)**. I need to count hourly ratio of a number of entries where response exists to the total number of entries on a specific date. The final selection should consist of columns "hour", "ratio".

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE RESPONSE IS NOT NULL//counting entries with response
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A//counting total number of entries
```

1. How to count the ratio? Should I create a separate variable for it?
2. How to count for each hour on a day? Should I make smth like a loop? + How can I get the "hour" part of a date?
3. What is the best way to select the hours and counted ratio? Should I make a separate table for it?

I`m rather new to make complex queries, so I woud be happy for every kind of help

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'HH24') as hour,
       count(response) as has_response, count(*) as total,
       count(response) / count(*) as ratio
from a
where datecol >= date '2018-09-18' and datecol < date '2018-09-19'
group by to_char(datecol, 'HH24');
```

You can also do this using `avg()` -- which is also fun:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'HH24'),
       avg(case when response is not null then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from a
where datecol >= date '2018-09-18' and datecol < date '2018-09-19'
group by to_char(datecol, 'HH24')
```

In this case, that requires more typing, though.

Comment: Sorry, mate, I wanted to upvote and clicked the upper arrow, but stack overflow threw a strange error

Comment: Very appreciate for your help, thank you. I will try that

Comment: Do note, that if you don't take the date into account, you will end up confusing hours from multiple different days. So they won't be accurate for specific dates (e.g. 1 september 13:00 to 13:59) but instead ( all days 13:00 to 13:59 ). You do try to compensate by filtering for specific dates, `but this means your query doesn't work for more than one day`!

Comment: When I try the first variant, it throws me an exception "not a single-group group function". I found out that may be because of using COUNT function in SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT withResponses.hour,
       withResponses.cnt AS withResponse,
       alls.cnt AS AllEntries,
       (withResponses.cnt / alls.cnt) AS ratio
FROM
  ( SELECT to_char(d, 'DD-MM-YY - HH24') || ':00 to :59 ' hour,
           count(*) AS cnt
   FROM A
   WHERE RESPONSE IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY to_char(d, 'DD-MM-YY - HH24') || ':00 to :59 ' ) withResponses,

  ( SELECT to_char(d, 'DD-MM-YY - HH24') || ':00 to :59 ' hour,
           count(*) AS cnt
   FROM A
   GROUP BY to_char(d, 'DD-MM-YY - HH24') || ':00 to :59 ' ) alls
WHERE alls.hour = withResponses.hour ;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c09b9/2

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Which tables do "alls" and "withResponses"  refer to?

Comment: Alls = aliased subquery containing all responses. WithResponses = aliased subtable where response is not null.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3c8a/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( dt, response, b_id ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '00:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'A',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '00:20' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'B',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'C',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '01:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'D',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '02:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '03:00' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'E',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-09-18' + INTERVAL '05:10' HOUR TO MINUTE, 'F',  1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT b_id,
       TO_CHAR( TRUNC( dt, 'HH' ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS hour,
       COUNT(RESPONSE) AS total_response_per_hour,
       COUNT(*)        AS total_per_hour,
       total_response_per_day,
       total_per_day,
       COUNT(response) / total_response_per_day AS ratio_for_responses,
       COUNT(*) / total_per_day AS ratio
FROM   (
  SELECT A.*,
         COUNT(RESPONSE) OVER ( PARTITION BY b_id, TRUNC( dt ) ) AS total_response_per_day,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY b_id, TRUNC( dt ) ) AS total_per_day
  FROM   A
)
GROUP BY
       b_id,
       total_per_day,
       total_response_per_day,
       TRUNC( dt, 'HH' )
ORDER BY
       TRUNC( dt, 'HH' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3c8a/3/0)**:

```
| B_ID |                HOUR | TOTAL_RESPONSE_PER_HOUR | TOTAL_PER_HOUR | TOTAL_RESPONSE_PER_DAY | TOTAL_PER_DAY | RATIO_FOR_RESPONSES | RATIO |
|------|---------------------|-------------------------|----------------|------------------------|---------------|---------------------|-------|
|    1 | 2018-09-18 00:00:00 |                       2 |              3 |                      6 |             8 |  0.3333333333333333 | 0.375 |
|    1 | 2018-09-18 01:00:00 |                       2 |              2 |                      6 |             8 |  0.3333333333333333 |  0.25 |
|    1 | 2018-09-18 02:00:00 |                       0 |              1 |                      6 |             8 |                   0 | 0.125 |
|    1 | 2018-09-18 03:00:00 |                       1 |              1 |                      6 |             8 | 0.16666666666666666 | 0.125 |
|    1 | 2018-09-18 05:00:00 |                       1 |              1 |                      6 |             8 | 0.16666666666666666 | 0.125 |
```